# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.' VB. Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Dim sql As String
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim odr As OleDbDataReader
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\e_alq\OneDrive\Desktop\a3\test.mdb"
    End Sub

       Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        con.Open()
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from test where basicsalary > 1  ", con)
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
        da.Fill(dt)
        ds.Tables.Clear()
        con.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: 1) I suggest that you remove the lines `ds.Tables.Add(dt)` and `ds.Tables.Clear()`. They are doing nothing useful in the code shown. 2) What is the type of the column `basicsalary` in the database?

Comment: 3) You don't need `con.Open()` and `con.Close()` because the `da.Fill(dt)` line does that automatically for you.

Comment: @LarsTech I get an error whenever I run the application : System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.' VB. Net

Comment: @AndrewMorton 1) I did remove them. 2) The datatype is Short Text but they are numbers in the database.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I did remove them and the error is still there

Comment: @ElyasAlQaseer Just because a string is made up of digits does not make it a number. Does `Select * from test where basicsalary > '1'` work? If it does, then it is very likely that you need to change the type of the column `basicsalary` to a suitable numeric type.